# How can I do an asc and desc sort using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am currently using underscorejs for sort my json sorting. Now I have asked to do an `ascending` and `descending` sorting using underscore.js. I do not see anything regarding the same in the documentation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add an example of what you are sorting and how.

Comment: What are you sorting? Numbers? Strings? Dates? Something else?

Comment: @muistooshort I am sorting an array of objects. So the sortBy method suits my criteria perfectly for ascending sort but not the other way round.

Comment: If you're sorting by a number then your `sortBy` function can be `return -n` but that won't work for strings; hence the question about what sorts of things you're sorting.

Comment: With Lodash you can use shorthand like `_.sortBy([1,4,3,2]).reverse()` or `_.chain([1,4,3,2]).sortBy().reverse().value()` if you don't want to use the `reverse()` prototype of Array.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

You can use [`.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy), it will always return an **ascending** list:

```
_.sortBy([2, 3, 1], function(num) {
    return num;
}); // [1, 2, 3]
```

But you can use the [.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method to get it **descending**:

```
var array = _.sortBy([2, 3, 1], function(num) {
    return num;
});

console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(array.reverse()); // [3, 2, 1]
```

Or when dealing with numbers add a negative sign to the return to descend the list:

```
_.sortBy([-3, -2, 2, 3, 1, 0, -1], function(num) {
    return -num;
}); // [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3]
```

Under the hood [`.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) uses the built in [`.sort([handler])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
// Default is alphanumeric ascending:
[2, 3, 1].sort(); // [1, 2, 3]

// But can be descending if you provide a sort handler:
[2, 3, 1].sort(function(a, b) {
    // a = current item in array
    // b = next item in array
    return b - a;
});
```

Comment: Last solution i.e. adding negetive sign to returned num is perfect.

Comment: Why would you think it's bubble sort? Under the hood `.sortBy()` calls built-in `Array.sort()`, the algorithm of which is up to the browser vendors, but bubble sort is pretty unlikely to be their choice.

Comment: Doesn't this increase the time complexity?  It causes the list to be sorted twice.

Comment: @user1477388 I'm not sure what you mean about sorted twice?

Comment: @andlrc So, when you call `_.sortBy(arr, function)`, I assume it loops over each item and executes some logic to return the sorted array.  Then, when you call `Array.prototype.reverse()` it probably loops over each item again and executes some logic to return the reversed array.  Therefore, you are looping the array twice.

Comment: If you are chaining sortBys together would you have to chain reverse between all of them? eg `_.chain(list).sortBy('height').reverse().sortBy('width').reverse().value()`

Answer (score 59):

Descending order using underscore can be done by multiplying the return value by -1.

```
//Ascending Order:
_.sortBy([2, 3, 1], function(num){
    return num;
}); // [1, 2, 3]


//Descending Order:
_.sortBy([2, 3, 1], function(num){
    return num * -1;
}); // [3, 2, 1]
```

If you're sorting by strings not numbers, you can use the charCodeAt() method to get the unicode value.

```
//Descending Order Strings:
_.sortBy(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(s){ 
    return s.charCodeAt() * -1;
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to sort alphabetically - multiplying by -1 is not a valid operation. :)

Comment: Its a worth while use case but not specified in the question. However, multiplying a string by -1 is a valid operation. It returns NaN, which is a valid result.

Comment: remember to assign the array back too !

    SOME_ARR = _.sortBy(SOME_ARR, function(num){ SOME_FUNC ... });

Comment: charCodeAt will "return the Unicode of the character at the specified index in a string" so it can be used to sort by characters in a string, but as shown it does *not* "sort by string" it sorts by a character in the string

Comment: This only sorts by the first character, and it is case sensitive.

Comment: Can someone helo on Loadash _SortyBy alphabetically?. I have an object with multiple columns and i wanna sort by particular column which the user chooses in the UI. Default implementation of Loadash sortby uses ascii character

Comment: Very clever. I like this solution a lot more than doing a sort than doing a _.reverse afterwords.

Answer (score 53):

The [Array prototype's reverse method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) modifies the array and returns a reference to it, which means you can do this:

```
var sortedAsc = _.sortBy(collection, 'propertyName');
var sortedDesc = _.sortBy(collection, 'propertyName').reverse();
```

Also, the underscore documentation reads:

> In addition, the [Array prototype's methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) are proxied through the chained Underscore object, so you can slip a `reverse` or a `push` into your chain, and continue to modify the array.

which means you can also use `.reverse()` while chaining:

```
var sortedDescAndFiltered = _.chain(collection)
    .sortBy('propertyName')
    .reverse()
    .filter(_.property('isGood'))
    .value();
```

Comment: This is by fare the simplest method for reverse/descending sorting when it comes to most simple use cases.

Comment: To do a case-insensitive alphabetical sort: `_.sortBy(collection, item => item. propertyName.toLowerCase());`

Comment: this doesn't work if there are negative numbers in the array.

Comment: @ShrutiKapoor Yes it does. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Performance-wise, it would be preferable to first apply the filter and then to sort (the remaining) values.

Answer (score 13):

Similar to Underscore library there is another library called as 'lodash' that has one method "orderBy" which takes in the parameter to determine in which order to sort it. You can use it like

```
_.orderBy('collection', 'propertyName', 'desc')
```

For some reason, it's not documented on the website docs.

Comment: I think you confused [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) with [lodash](https://lodash.com/). Only the latter has the mentioned [orderBy function](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#orderBy).

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Will update the answer. Thanks for correcting :)

Comment: `orderBy`, super useful! Much better than using reverse, as it preserves the stable sort property that I'm looking for.

Comment: Not working for me for some reason
upadte: its lodash (

Answer (score 0):

**Underscore Mixins**

Extending on @emil_lundberg's answer, you can also write a "mixin" if you're using Underscore to make a custom function for sorting if it's a kind of sorting you might repeat in an application somewhere.

For example, maybe you have a controller or view sorting results with sort order of "ASC" or "DESC", and you want to toggle between that sort, you could do something like this:

**Mixin.js**

```
_.mixin({
    sortByOrder: function(stooges, prop, order) {
      if (String(order) === "desc") {
          return _.sortBy(stooges, prop).reverse();
      } else if (String(order) === "asc") {
          return _.sortBy(stooges, prop);
      } else {
          return stooges;
      }
    }
})
```

**Usage Example**

```
var sort_order = "asc";
var stooges = [
  {name: 'moe', age: 40}, 
  {name: 'larry', age: 50}, 
  {name: 'curly', age: 60},
  {name: 'July', age: 35},
  {name: 'mel', age: 38}
 ];

_.mixin({
    sortByOrder: function(stooges, prop, order) {
    if (String(order) === "desc") {
        return _.sortBy(stooges, prop).reverse();
    } else if (String(order) === "asc") {
        return _.sortBy(stooges, prop);
    } else {
        return stooges;
    }
  }
})


// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message");
var sort_name_btn = $("button.sort-name");
var sort_age_btn = $("button.sort-age");

function showSortedResults(results, sort_order, prop) {
    banner.empty();
    banner.append("<p>Sorting: " + prop + ', ' + sort_order + "</p><hr>")
  _.each(results, function(r) {
    banner.append('<li>' + r.name + ' is '+ r.age + ' years old.</li>');
  }) 
}

// handle click and add class
sort_name_btn.on("click", function() {
  sort_order = (sort_order === "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"; 
    var sortedResults = _.sortByOrder(stooges, 'name', sort_order);
  showSortedResults(sortedResults, sort_order, 'name');
})

sort_age_btn.on('click', function() {
    sort_order = (sort_order === "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"; 
    var sortedResults = _.sortByOrder(stooges, 'age', sort_order);
  showSortedResults(sortedResults, sort_order, 'age');
})
```

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this: [JSFiddle for SortBy Mixin](https://jsfiddle.net/zadLtr7j/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have reverse order in the first iteration:

```
_.sortBy([2, 3, 1], num => -num )
```