# How to sort ACS in js sortBy and Join?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, 'Category');
   groupedData = _.sortBy(groupedData, function (f) { return [f[0].CategoryID, f[0].Category].join("_"); });
```

This return descending in the result. I want it to return result ascending.
I tried to add sort() but it say `Sort is not a function`.
Is there another way of sorting it in ascending.

Comment: Where is your object?

Comment: There is not enough information provided.  Please provide minimal snippet of code to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided much information here. I assume you're using the underscore library.

See [How can I do an asc and desc sort using underscore.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137948/how-can-i-do-an-asc-and-desc-sort-using-underscore-js) for an answer to the same question, with extra detail.

Also see the underscore library documentation for _sortBy here: https://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

In short, as stated in the documentation, the sortBy() function returns the list in ascending order as determined by running each value through the iteratee, where the iteratee is the second parameter, and can be in the form of a function or string to determine the sort;

`_.sortBy(list, iteratee, [context])`

It seems you're attempting to use the iteratee to manipulate the values, as opposed to being used to determine the sort order.

For example, if you wanted to sort by the CategoryId, your code could look like:

`var sortedList = _.sortBy(list, 'CategoryId');`

Or it could look like

`var sortedList = _.sortBy(list, function (item) { return item.CategoryId; });`